# Bash - length of command line argument $0

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I want to find the length of $0

If I use the following bash code

```
leading-space=${#0}
```

I get the following result:

./Install: line 25: leading-space=9: command not found

$0 has the value ¨./Install¨

The length of the string appears to be correct, but then bash gets confused. I am running bash 5.0.17 on Ubuntu 20.10. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Identifiers in bash may not contain `-`, therefore the whole assignment is interpreted as a command (like `cd`, or `grep`) but there is no command with the name `leading-space=9` on your system, resulting in the error.

Use the following:

```
leading_space=${#0}
```